# Python Sendmail with Attachment?

Tags: python, mime-types, sendmail

I am programming with python. I already have a function that sends mails with attachments, but the problem is that it takes the message and puts it as an attachment. I need that it respects the message as message and the attachment as attachment. I have investigated and I found that has to do with MIME Multipart "MIXED" but i don't know how to add or change this to my actual functions.

Here is the python code of the function I am using:

```
def enviarCorreo(fromaddr, toaddr, file):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = 'asunto'
    #adjunto
    adjunto = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    adjunto.set_payload(open(file, "rb").read())
    encode_base64(adjunto)
    adjunto.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename= "%s"' % file)
    msg.attach(adjunto)
    #enviar
    server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
    return
```

Comment: Sorry for the order of the code.....dont know why it appears this way!!

Comment: Next time, select your code then use the button with {} on it to get formatting.

Comment: Where do you add your actual email message?

Comment: actually that is part of my problem....I dont know how to add the email message....
I found that the function SENDMAIL takes as parameters (FROM,TO,MESSAGE)...I am already using the MESSAGE parameter to send the file I'm attaching....so I dont know where to put the actual message wich would be HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to attach the text as msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )

```
def enviarCorreo(fromaddr, toaddr, text, file):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = 'asunto'

    #This is the part you had missed.
    msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )

    #adjunto
    adjunto = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    adjunto.set_payload( open(file,"rb").read() )
    Encoders.encode_base64(adjunto)
    adjunto.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(file))
    msg.attach(adjunto)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, msg.as_string())
    server.close()

enviarCorreo("x@from.com", ["y@to.com"], "Hello World", ['/tmp/sample.png'])
```

See if this works for you.

Comment: The code works very well if I want to add a plain text message, but what should I change if I want the message to be HTML???

THANKS!!!

Comment: @mauguerra replace the line#8 with msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'html'))

Answer (score 0):

You might find an answer (and additional useful ideas) in the [email module examples](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html).

One examples seems to use `msg.preamble = "..."` for the main message text.

Comment: outer.preamble will not show as text in a MIME-aware mail reader. The document mentions that. For example AppleMail. - EDIT -  Doesn't work for Google WebMail either.

Comment: What exactly does the msg.preamble does????
I tried to use it but it stop sending emails

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.preamble explained here.